# Invalid link to moderator tools description

Tags: bug, status-completed

I just got the following message in the achievements list on the [Stack Exchange main page](https://stackexchange.com/) (100% reproducible):

> [You've earned the "access to moderator tools" privilege! Learn more about it in the help center.](https://stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)

It seems the subdomain is stripped from links on stackexchange.com - the link should be https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools, not https://stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools. The latter results in a 404 error.